# How to merge two onEdit so I can run two scripts on the same sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know there are probably many posts about the same thing but I don't understand a thing at all. I haven't slept for an entire day just reading all about this. I have ZERO knowledge about scripts and I've been cramming information for the past few hours.

I just need help merging two onEdit scripts together since I've read that one sheet can only run one onEdit script.

My first script (that I copy-pasted from online) is to auto-hide a row based on a specific value:

```
function myFunction() {
  
}
var SHEET = "2022";

var VALUE = "Cancelled/Removed";

var COLUMN_NUMBER = "6"

function onEdit(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){

var cell = ss.getActiveCell()

var cellValue = cell.getValue();

if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){

if(cellValue == VALUE){

activeSheet.hideRow(cell);

};  

};

};

}
```

And this is the 2nd script to automatically input the exact time when I input value into a cell:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "2022" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

If someone could help me with this, if possible, in the most simplified way possible. I really don't understand most of these stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option for you is to just combine them into one function. Like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var SHEET = "2022";
var VALUE = "Cancelled/Removed";
var COLUMN_NUMBER = "6"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
var cellValue = cell.getValue();
if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
if(cellValue == VALUE){
activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
}}}
if( activeSheet.getName() == "2022" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
if(r.getValue() != ""){ 
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}}}}
```

Note: I added `if(r.getValue() != ""){`  so that it only puts the date in the adjacent cell if you actually put a value in the cell. If you want it to update the date even if you just delete something you will want to get rid of that line and one of the `}` at the end.